# What is the time complexity of delete in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

```
const obj = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: 3
};
const isDeleted = delete obj.b;
```

What is the time complexity of delete functionality here. Is it O(1)? How does it work internally?

Comment: The object is a hash table, so it's just removing an entry from the hash table, which is O(1)

Comment: @Barmar What about collisions? In the worst case, the deletion would be O(n)

Comment: @HeilProgrammierung More precisely, it's considered "asymptotic O(1)". The collisions are in the noise. The same goes for the expense of rehashing.

Comment: @Barmar well, yeah, assuming 99% of the time we won't have any collisions, we can say it's O(1) in general.

Comment: The problem is that collision frequency is dependent on hidden state, like the number of buckets in the hash table or the hash function. This can even change dynamically. So we ignore it because it's not possible to account for it unless you're analyzing the hash table implementation rather than its use.